# Генерация кнопок

Tags: python, tkinter, generate

Имеется: список имён изображений для нанесения их на кнопки (**image_list**), переменные **image_list = "../Images"** и **image_int = len(os.listdir(image_dir))**.

После запускается цикл *for x in range(imagelist)*:

В теле цикла:

```
Y = 0
Y+= 10

#ImageLink = PhotoImage(file="../Images/img%i"% i +".gif")
FrameButton = Button(root,text=images_names[i],
                     width=10,height=1,
                     relief=GROOVE).grid(row=0,column=Y)
```

Проблема заключается в том, что в левом-верхнем углу размещается лишь последняя кнопка из списка, а не столбиком (сверху вниз).

И второй вопрос заключается в том, как каждой сгенерированной кнопке назначить ссылку на разные изображения, учитывая, что имя изображения также генерируется в цикле (**"img%i"%i.gif"**).

Comment: "кнопки не размещаются с верхнего-левого края" -- чего?
"назначить ссылку на разные изображения" -- зачем?

Comment: 
Если имеется в виду функция на кнопке, то используйте

    command=lambda par=par: call_function(par)

Comment: Вы точно хотите всем кнопка дать одно название?
Может вместо FrameButton = ... написать FrameButtons.append(..), предварительно сделав это списком?
Приведите бОльший кусок кода, чтобы можно было только поправить, а не писать заново. 
Уп-с... два года назад.